# JQuery Mobile PDF Viewer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to use a pdf viewer with jquery mobile and asp.net mvc? I want to grab a pdf file and display it in my mobile site. I think I am suppose to use jquery mobile for my controls but I am not sure how to apply a pdf viewer. My mobile site is created using asp.net mvc and jquery mobile

Am I looking at this correctly?

Comment: You can just use the mobile browser to render the PDF file.

Comment: do you have a link to a tutorial on that?

Comment: My guess is that asp.net mvc can create images from PDFs, I use ColdFusion to do that, so the document can be viewed inline from any browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply return the file using the [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492593.aspx) method of `Controller` class. If the client has a PDF reader, everything will be fine.

```
public ActionResult ShowFile()
{
  string path="FullPAthTosomefile.pdf";
  return File(path, "application/pdf","someFriendlyName.pdf");
}
```

You can return the file from a stream & byte array also. There are so many [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file.aspx) for these scenarios.

When accessing this action method in a browser,the file-stream result object will be rendered to the browser. You do not need a separate view for this.

Comment: I dont need to do anything to the View to display this?..kinda new with this stuff

Comment: no. You dont need a view for this. Just request the url like your domainname/yourcontrollername/ShowFile. the file will be rendered to the browser.

Comment: Mobile devices will download the PDF, is that correct? I'm not familiar with any mobile browsers that show PDFs inline, are there some that do?